# How to rename files in directory with its sha1 hash with python?

Tags: python, hash

I need to rename my files in directory with its hash with Python. I've done the same thing using C#:

```
   Console.Write("enter path");
        string path = Console.ReadLine();

        foreach (var i in Directory.GetFiles(path))
        {
            try
            {
                using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
                {
                    FileStream f = new FileStream(i.ToString(), FileMode.Open);
                    byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(f);
                    string formatted = string.Empty;
                    foreach (byte b in hash)
                    {
                        formatted += b.ToString("X2");
                    }
                    f.Close();

                    File.Move(i.ToString(), path+"//" + formatted);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
            }
```

Can someone help me get started with what I'd use in Python to accomplish the same? I'll be using Ubuntu, if it makes any difference.

Comment: First of all, why not compile your C# code under Ubuntu? It will run just fine. Second, what is your specific question? What have you tried? This is not a free code conversion site that employs humans to do the thinking for you.

Comment: I agree with Jim: you have the C# code, why convert it, when you can just run it. Mono might not be perfect, but I'm pretty sure it will run that code just fine.

Comment: if you dont convert please offer link( article sample) for me  please!!  i should write it with python

Answer (score 4):

In Python if you want to compute some hash (MD5, SHA1) there is [`hashlib`](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html) module.
To make some operations on filesystem there is [`os`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) module. In those modules you will find: `sha1` object with `hexdigest()` method and `listdir()` and `rename()` functions. Example code:

```
import os
import hashlib

def sha1_file(fn):
    f = open(fn, 'rb')
    r = hashlib.sha1(f.read()).hexdigest()
    f.close()
    return r

for fn in os.listdir('.'):
    if fn.endswith('.sha'):
        hexh = sha1_file(fn)
        print('%s -> %s' % (fn, hexh))
        os.rename(fn, hexh)
```

*Attention*: `sha1_file()` function read whole file at once so it will not work very well for huge files. As a homework try to improve it for such files (read file in parts and update hash with those parts).

Of course `if fn.endswith('.sha'):` is used for test purposes only.